# How do I add column names to a select that is doing unnest struct in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I am constructing a table using given values like this

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST
([ STRUCT
(1, 3.07766, 6.31371, 12.7062, 63.65600),
(2, 1.88562, 2.91999, 4.30265, 9.92482),
(3, 1.63774, 2.35336, 3.18243, 5.84089)
])
```

which creates columns with names `fn_` as this

| Row | f0_ | f1_ | f2_ | f3_ | f4_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I would like to name columns **without putting AS statements into STRUCT**,
so **not like**

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST
([ STRUCT
(1 as a, 3.07766 as b, 6.31371 as c, 12.7062 as d, 63.65600 as e),
(2, 1.88562, 2.91999, 4.30265, 9.92482),
(3, 1.63774, 2.35336, 3.18243, 5.84089)
])
```

I understand that it works, but the question is can we do something like

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST
([ STRUCT
(1, 3.07766, 6.31371, 12.7062, 63.65600),
(2, 1.88562, 2.91999, 4.30265, 9.92482),
(3, 1.63774, 2.35336, 3.18243, 5.84089)
]) as (a, b, c, d, e)
```

and that is because this SELECT is constructed by Python code to be used in MERGE statement that updates existing values in a table with a constructed table.

If there is any other way you think it's better to construct temporary table with given values in BigQuery, please share your ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below option

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST
([ STRUCT<a int64, b float64, c float64, d float64, e float64>
(1, 3.07766, 6.31371, 12.7062, 63.65600),
(2, 1.88562, 2.91999, 4.30265, 9.92482),
(3, 1.63774, 2.35336, 3.18243, 5.84089)
])
```

from your Python code point of view  - it should be equivalent to what you want. So that line with column names - moved to STRUCT definition line and does not touch the values rows

Comment: uffff, the fact that I have to give data types explicitly opens a whole new can of worms, because the solution is supposed to be applicable to multiple tables and each of them is a mixture of ints, floats, strings, dates and datetimes

Comment: understood, this leaves you with only option of having your Python code smart enough to ad column names into first set of values so then types will be derived from values in the first set

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thank you, Mikhail

Comment: So Mikhail was right after all! Inferring types like (1 as a, 3.07766 as b, 6.31371 as c, 12.7062 as d, 63.65600 as e) is not gonna work in case your first line happens to have a NULL, BQ cannot infer type from NULL. So I ended up parametrizing schema externally and do Mikhail's syntax. Alternatively you can do SELECT column_name,data_type FROM priject.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS WHERE table_name = 'tablename'. Giving Mikhail his well deserved "accepted answer"!

Answer (score 1):

As much as I don't like it, I will probably have to go with

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST
([ STRUCT
(1 as a, 3.07766 as b, 6.31371 as c, 12.7062 as d, 63.65600 as e),
(2, 1.88562, 2.91999, 4.30265, 9.92482),
(3, 1.63774, 2.35336, 3.18243, 5.84089)
])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Meh, not gonna work if you have NULLs in first line. Accepting Mikhail's answer